# Execute JQuery Function on div view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, I'm looking for a solution for a webpage. I have a function that increase a text number but I need that the function begin on view the section. This is the function and works fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  
    $("#chartdiv").one("inview", function(event, isInView)
        {                   
        if (isInView) 
        {
            alert("calling function");
            $.fn.numbers();
        }
    });

          /*INCREASE TEXT NUMBER*/
          $.fn.numbers = function() { 
          //$(function numbers() {
            var initialDate = new Date(2013, 06, 1);
            var now = Date.now();
            var difference = now - initialDate;
            var millisecondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            var daysSince = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);
            var daysSongs = Math.floor(difference / millisecondsPerDay);
            daysSince = (daysSince * 3);
            daysSongs= (daysSongs * 12);


            //INCREASE FUNCTION
            $({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: daysSince}, {
               duration: 3000,
               easing:'swing', // can be anything
               step: function() { // called on every step --DO NOT EXECUTE ???
                // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:

                $('#days_since').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
               }
            });


            $({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: daysSongs}, {
               duration: 3000,
               easing:'swing', // can be anything
               step: function() { // called on every step
               // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
               $('#days_songs').text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.round(this.someValue)));
               }
             });

            };
            /**/
        });         


          //ADD COMMAS  
          function commaSeparateNumber(val){
            while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString()))
            {
            val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
            }
            return val;
            }
```

Using JQuery INVIEW, but the INCREASE FUNCTION is not TRIGGERED

Comment: It doesn't matter what your function is. What have you tried to trigger it when the div is in view?

Comment: Exactly! I want to trigger it when the div is in view.

Answer (score 1):

Ripped this from a plugin I wrote:

```
var $watched = $('#feed-link-text a');

var doWhenSeen = function () {
    $watched.html('<span class="feed-icon"></span>Why hello there!!')
};

var checkVisible = function (elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom >= docViewTop) && (elemTop <= docViewBottom)
            && (elemBottom <= docViewBottom) &&  (elemTop >= docViewTop) );
}


var visibleCheckInterval = window.setInterval( function () {
    if ( checkVisible( $watched[0]) )
        doWhenSeen();
}, 250);
```

To see this work, **scroll to the top of this SO page,  paste above code into the console, then scroll down to the RSS feed link** (if this is months later and it shows an error, just replace $watched's css selector with an element on this page).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if  ( $(element).is(":visible") ) { do something }
```

or one more solution:

```
    $.fn.visible = function(partial) {
        var $t        = $(this),
            $w            = $(window),
            viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
            viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height() + 100,
            _top          = $t.offset().top,
            _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
            compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
            compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;
        return (viewBottom > compareBottom);
    };

if (el.visible(true)) { do something ...
```

Comment: Sorry but I tried and It doesn't work. I'm trying using JQuery Inview, still no solution.